# Skip the folder names in the localhost server url?

Tags: url-rewriting

Actually I am working on a project on my local wamp server. I need to redirect the main page from this

URL ------>`localhost/aftabcurrency/cpanel/main_page.php`

to the following

url `localhost/aftabcurrency/main_page.php`

I have tried this rewriting code in m .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^main_page.php$     /aftabcurrency/cpanel/main_page.php [L]
```

and also this one

```
RewriteRule ^main_page.php$     aftabcurrency/cpanel/main_page.php [L]
```

but its giving an error of Not FOUND...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^aftabcurrency/cpanel/main_page.php$ aftabcurrency/main_page.php [L]
```

You're redirecting it infinite when you only define `main_page.php`.

Comment: You want to direct /cpanel/main_page.php to /main_page.php? Or the other way around?